# Firestore security rules: Using hasOnly on a request to check if only a specific field is updated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm setting up my Firestore security rules, but run against one issue wherein I want to limit updating only one specific field within a document by using the hasOnly function. The problem is that I keep getting 'denied' results using the simulator. I'm surely doing something simple wrong... I'm trying to prevent that somebody could update other fields in the document than `update_requested_time`, but allow them to update this particular field.

When using the example from the Firestore documentation on hasOnly() — `['a', 'b'].hasOnly(['b', 'a']) == true` — the rule returns true. But when using my own it does not, by that I assume I'm getting something wrong in the part of `request.resource.data.keys()`.

**The specific rule targeting fields in a specific *scenario*:**

```
match /scenarios/{scenario} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['update_requested_time']) == true;
```

**The simulator request I'm sending (update with authentication):**

```
{"__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/scenarios/test1","data":{"update_requested_time":"2019-02-05T11:00:00.000Z"}}
```

**My complete rules:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /scenarios/{scenario} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['update_requested_time']) == true;
      match /comments/{comment} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow delete,update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
      }
      match /outputs/{tile} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
      match /mutations/{tile} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create,update: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
    }
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == user;
    }
  }
}
```

[screenshot of firestore rules + simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY4lc.png)

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted what request.resource.data contains, I was assuming it contained the request data itself, but it rather contains the new version of the resource after the write operation.

Firestore documentation on request.resource:
`The new resource value, present on write requests only.`

Comment: So, is this issue resolved?  Do you want to answer your own question, or simply close it as a misunderstanding?

Comment: If it means that there is no way to have one field writeable and to have another field that is not, then this question can be closed as a misunderstanding I guess.

Comment: I've put it up as an answer anyway, maybe it helps somebody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request.resource.data` doesn't contain the request data itself, but it rather contains the new version of the resource after the write operation. Therefore the check failed.

Firestore documentation on `request.resource`:

> The new resource value, present on write requests only.

Comment: How can i check the incoming request keys

Comment: Haven’t checked the documentation on this lately, but at the time it didn’t seem possible to check incoming request keys. Just the resulting updated data of it.

Comment: Did they introduced anything new..!

Comment: Maybe this could be a solution https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

Answer (score 12):

Looks like the right way to do this now is

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["update_requested_time"])
```

Found from [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/WmDd5L6K-Qc/m/Dqnel8VPAgAJ) conversation

Comment: Works with latest versions as of 2023-06-20

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misreading this, but isn't a solution to have your rule do a deep comparison between `request.data` and `request.resource.data` to confirm that only the one field changed?

Maybe there is a cleaner way, but what about:

```
import _ from "lodash";

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function onlyRequestTimeChanged(currValue, newValue) {
      let newCopy = _.cloneDeep(newValue)
      newCopy.update_requested_time = currValue.update_requested_time

      return _.isEqual(currValue, newCopy)
    }

    match /scenarios/{scenario} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if onlyRequestTimeChanged(request.resource,data, request.data)
  // ...
}
```