# Firebase Rules, Trying to add strict measures

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've created this rule here:

```
match /Users/{document} {
      // function
      function isUpdatingTradeURL() {
        return request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified'])
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified'])
      }

      allow update: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID) && isUpdatingTradeURL()
}
```

And trying to update it with the following data:

```
{
  userSteamTradeVerified: true,
  userSteamTradePartnerID: partnerID,
  userSteamTradeToken: token
}
```

But the rules seem to fail everytime? Any ideas? Might be something so simple.

So, out of curiosity I tried to do this:

```
request.resource.data.keys().size() == 3
```

and of course that failed... however doing this:

```
request.resource.data.keys().size() == 4
```

Works.... is there a hidden field?

Here is the full update function:

````
this.$fireStore.collection('Users').doc(this.userID).update({
            userSteamTradeVerified: true,
            userSteamTradePartnerID: partnerID,
            userSteamTradeToken: token
          })
    ```
````

Comment: Just to be sure, what happens if you only set `allow update: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID)`

Comment: Yeah that works (there is a userID within the document we are trying to update)

Comment: return request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified']) on its own also works!

Comment: okay, and when checking for `return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified'])`?

Comment: Check my edit above ^^

Comment: Does your document contain 4 keys in total, because it seems like the check you do is a check on the updated document -> See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505235/10851607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505235/10851607 the request.resource data contains the future data:

> When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the request.resource variable contains the future state of the document.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

So when you want to check for updated data try this one:

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);`
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

Comment: So the hasOnly are making sure that the write has ONLY affect the keys in the list, is that correct?

Comment: The document we are updating has around 15 different fields in it

Comment: So in you case you could try the diff(...).affectedKeys() with hasOnly() and hasAll(), like you did. before, according to the docs that should work, but I could not check it out due to some problems with my wsl

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden field, it is just that `request.resource.data` represent the future state including ALL fields, updated and non updated ones.

Like @Tanja suggested, try the following:

```
match /Users/{document} {
  function isUpdatingTradeURL() {
    let changedkeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
    let allowedkeys = ['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified'];
    return changedkeys.hasAll(allowedkeys) && changedkeys.hasOnly(allowedkeys)
  }
  allow update: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID) && isUpdatingTradeURL()
}
```

This ensures the listed fields are changed and only them.

Beware, if any of them is not changed, the rule will fail. If you can split them into optional and mandatory then use this:

```
match /Users/{document} {
  function isUpdatingTradeURL() {
    let changedkeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
    let mustchangekeys = ['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken'];
    let canchangekeys = ['userSteamTradePartnerID', 'userSteamTradeToken', 'userSteamTradeVerified'];
    return changedkeys.hasAll(mustchangekeys) && changedkeys.hasOnly(canchangekeys)
  }
  allow update: if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID) && isUpdatingTradeURL()
}
```